# Cancel task on timeout in RxJava

Tags: java, future, rx-java, completable-future

I'm experimenting with RxJava and Java 8's CompletableFuture class 
and do not quite get how to handle timeout conditions.

```
import static net.javacrumbs.futureconverter.java8rx.FutureConverter.toObservable;

// ...

    Observable<String> doSomethingSlowly() {
        CompletableFuture<PaymentResult> task = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            // this call may be very slow - if it takes too long, 
            // we want to time out and cancel it.
            return processor.slowExternalCall();

        });

        return toObservable(task);
    }

    // ...

    doSomethingSlowly()
        .single()
        .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just("timeout"));
```

This basically works (if the timeout of three seconds is reached, "timeout" is published). I would however additionally want to cancel the future task that I've wrapped in an `Observable` - is that possible with an RxJava-centric approach?

I know that one option would be to handle the timeout myself, using `task.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, but I wonder if it's possible to do all task handling stuff in RxJava.

Comment: Could you show how `toObservable` method is implemented?

Comment: https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter/tree/master/rxjava-java8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You would add a `Subscription` to the `Subscriber`.

This allows you to listen in on unsubscriptions, which will happen if you explicitly call `subscribe().unsubscribe()` or if the `Observable` completes successfully or with an error.

If you see an unsubscription before the future has completed, you can assume it's because of either an explicit `unsubscribe` or a timeout.

```
public class FutureTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        doSomethingSlowly()
                .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just("timeout"))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
        System.in.read(); // keep process alive
    }

    private static Observable<String> doSomethingSlowly() {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return "Something";

        });
        return toObservable(future);
    }

    private static <T> Observable<T> toObservable(CompletableFuture<T> future) {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            subscriber.add(new Subscription() {
                private boolean unsubscribed = false;
                @Override
                public void unsubscribe() {
                    if (!future.isDone()){
                        future.cancel(true);
                    }
                    unsubscribed = true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isUnsubscribed() {
                    return unsubscribed;
                }
            });

            future.thenAccept(value -> {
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()){
                    subscriber.onNext(value);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            }).exceptionally(throwable -> {
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscriber.onError(throwable);
                }
                return null;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful pattern to know. In the meantime, I discovered that the [semantics of `CompletableFuture.cancel` are different from plain Futures](http://java.dzone.com/articles/completablefuture-cant-be) - you can't interrupt a `CompletableFuture` using the `cancel` method. 

The solution you suggest does  however translate nicely also to plain Futures, so I'm going with that.